# Auto chmod and launch?

Tags: command-line, usb, bash, chmod

Is there a way to have all files chmoded and then launched automatically?
Say when I have my pc off, I insert a usb stick with a game on it, a lot of random files need to be chmoded and then I would want that game to auto run.

I guess I could just add the `start.sh` to the auto run, but make sure every time I put a diff game on the usb I change the bash file name to `start.sh`?

Could I just make a simple bash script that would `chmod` everything on the usb, and add it to my start up programs?

Comment: Just a comment, for the `chmod` part, I don't think it is a good idea to have USB drives formated to ext2/3/4. If you use FAT or exFAT it would not even be a problem.

Comment: @bfrguci unless the USB drives are only used on Linux, in which case it's fine for ext2/3/4.  However, this question is vague - we don't know what they're really trying to do here.

Comment: @ThomasW. It is still a bad idea even if it is only used on Linux. The privileges will be troublesome because the UID of your user on some other computer may not be the same with that on your computer, and you will lose access to it that way, unless all files on it has owner/group as root:root - which is still troublesome.

Comment: @bfrguci True, but this is an opinion, and to each their own opinion.

Comment: the usb drive will only be used on linux,

Comment: basically i have an old'ish mITX board with an amd r7 card in it, its tiny enuf to hide away!
want to have a USB cable just popping out that i can put a flash drive in and it boot that game?

the usb drives wont be used on othher machines to play the game, but i may use another machine to put a different game on it

Answer (score 0):

Install `inotify-tools`. Then something like this would work, I believe:

```
while true
do
    inotifywait /media/$USER
    find /media/$USER -type f -exec chmod +x {} \;
done
```